# How to call a class infinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this piece of code which runs infinitely. I want to put this code in a class and define a button in another class. When the button is clicked, it should call the class (in which the code is) and this class should run infinitely like the original code. As I have tried several methods which I learnt from internet but no luck at all. As I'm totally new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation

j=0
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.093, 0.04, 0.8])
cax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

H = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 6, 10], [3, 7, 8, 4], [10, 5, 3, 1]])
Z = np.array([[3, 290, 600], [1011, 230, 830], [152, 750, 5]])


def func(i):
    global j
    if j == 0:
        j += 1
        rows, cols = H.shape

        im = plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest',
                    extent=[0, cols, 0, rows],
                    cmap='bwr', vmin=0, vmax=10)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical')

    elif j == 1:
        j -= 1
        rows, cols = H.shape

        im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Spectral', vmin=0, vmax=1023,
                    extent=[0, cols, 0, rows])
        v = np.linspace(0, 1023, 15, endpoint=True)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=ax1, orientation='vertical', ticks=v)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

It should be better to use `Canvas` instead of `imshow`because later on I will make a GUI and will use Tkinter.

Comment: You can just embed the plot in Tkinter assuming that's the other class you meant upon button click to update / change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a function `do_something` which you want to call repeatedly in a loop:

```
def do_something(...):
    <whatever code you want>
```

Assuming you pass in a reference to a widget (eg: `root`), you can run this function continuously with something like the following example. In this example it runs the code every second (eg: 1000 ms).

```
def run_every_second(root):
    do_something()
    root.after(1000, run_every_second, root)
```

You start the process by calling `run_every_second` just once:

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
run_every_second(root)
```

I do not know if this method works well in conjunction with matplotlib, but with normal tkinter this is a very standard technique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using `canvas.show()` instead of `plt.show()` which is not updating. I used your technique but still the same thing, no update.